# Unable to resolve "@react-navigation/drawer" from "App.js" - React Native

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I have issues with drawer. I have follow tutorial and create drawer navigation with React Native and I got this error on iOS. But android works fine.

Note : I have installed drawer package into my project

Comment: have you done pod install ?

Comment: No i havent ... can you explain ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you have an issue with your pod installation..

After you installed package to your dependencies you need to do pod installation

**Follow these steps**

1. Move to your ios folder using `cd ios`
2. Run this command `pod install`
3. Open your project using xcode and clean ( Command+Shift+K )
4. Finally run your project ( Command + R )

Comment: I will try this.. Thanks for your answer

Comment: @DeSilva glad it helps